# How to convert a system of parametric equations to a normal equation?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation, inverse

For example,  I have a system of parametric equations (`R` is a constant number) :

```
{ x == p +  R Cos[k],
  y == Cos[p] +  R Sin[k],
  k == ArcTan[ 1/Sin[p] ]   }
```

Now I am going to find the normal equation of $\; y = f(x)\;$ without other variables. (Theoretically it is possible because there are totally 4 variables and 3 equations.)

How can I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Is `px` a variable, or is it `p * x` ? What about `py` ?

Comment: @Artes they are variables, sorry for confusing. I have already eliminated `py`, and rename `px` to `p`.

Comment: But there are 5 variables in your 3 equations. Otherwise, perhaps you can use Eliminate.

Comment: @yulinlinyu there are `x`,`y`,`p`,`k` 4 variables in the 3 equations. `R` is a constant number. I wonder how to do elimination in Mathematica.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, for the sake of simplicity let's define `eqs` - the system of our interest :

```
eqs = { x == p + R Cos[k],
        y == Cos[p] + R Sin[k],
        k == ArcTan[ 1/Sin[p]]  };
```

#### Equations y = y(x)

For this system we can find an explicit equation $\;y = y(x)\;$ only assuming `R == 0`, otherwise we could find only implicit solutions.

```
Solve[ eqs /. R -> 0, y, {p}, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> {{y -> ConditionalExpression[Cos[x], k == ArcTan[Csc[x]]]}}
> ```

See e.g. [Inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) for the general issue of invertibility, let's restrict to :

```
eqs[[1]] /. (Rule @@@ eqs)[[3]]
```

> ```
> x == p + R/Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2]
> ```

When `R` is given, one could invert $\;x = x(p)\;$  in a neighbourhood of $p_{0}$ to get $\;p = p(x)\;$ if $\frac{dx}{dp}|_{p=p_{0}} \neq 0$, i.e.    only for special ranges of `p` where $\frac{dx}{dp}$ doesn't vanish.  While it would work well on the symbolic level using `InverseFunction`, but generically there is no way to get explicit formulae. We can animate dependence of the function $\;x = x(p)\;$ : `p + R Cos[ArcTan[1/Sin[p]]]` and its inverse function $\;p = p(x)\;$ on the running parameter `-1 < R < 1` (then $x(p)$ is globally invertible). We add  the symmetry axis `p == x`.

```
Animate[ Plot[ { p + R Cos[ArcTan[1/Sin[p]]],
                 p,
                 InverseFunction[ # + R Cos[ ArcTan[ 1/Sin[#]]] &]@p }, {p, -Pi, Pi},

               PlotPoints -> 80, PlotRange -> {-3.3, 3.3},
               PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Thick}],
         {R, -1, 1} ]
```

[image]

#### Equations y = y(k)

We can get an equation for `y` in an implicit form using `Eliminate` and then solve the equation with respect to `y` :

```
Eliminate[ eqs, {x, p}, InverseFunctions -> True]
Reduce[%, y]
```

> ```
> (-1 + y^2 - 2 R y Sin[k] + R^2 Sin[k]^2) Tan[k]^2 == -1
>
> Tan[k] != 0 && 
> (y == Cot[k]^2 (R Sin[k] Tan[k]^2 - Sqrt[-Tan[k]^2 + Tan[k]^4]) || 
>  y == Cot[k]^2 (R Sin[k] Tan[k]^2 + Sqrt[-Tan[k]^2 + Tan[k]^4])    )
> ```

We've got solutions in terms of `k` only. This is the best one can do for your system,
otherwise to get an equation for `y` in terms of `x` we should invert $\;k = k(x)\;$ to get $\;y = y(x)\;$

```
First @ Solve[ k == ArcTan[ Csc[ p]], p]
```

> ```
> {p -> ArcCsc[Tan[k]]}
> ```

We could do that analogically as in the case $\;p = p(x)\;$, i.e using `InverseFunction`.

#### Equations y = y(p)

You could as well try another way of eliminating variables while solving equations (as pointed out by Searke) i.e. `Solve[ eqns, vars, elims]`, and using `MaxExtraConditions -> All` to get also non-generic solutions, here we eliminate `k` to get a solution in terms of `p` :

```
Solve[ eqs, y, k, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> {{y -> ConditionalExpression[(R Csc[p] + Cos[p] Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2])/ Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2], 
>                                Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2] != 0 &&
>                                p - x + R/Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2] == 0]}}
> ```

The second argument in `ConditionalExpression` is the condition which has to be satisfied.

Nevertheless you could do the following to express `y` in terms of `p` and `x` :

```
Solve[ eqs, {y, k}]
```

> ```
> {{y -> -Sqrt[-p^2 + R^2 + 2 p x - x^2] + Cos[p], k -> ArcTan[Csc[p]]},
>  {y -> Sqrt[-p^2 + R^2 + 2 p x - x^2] + Cos[p], k -> ArcTan[Csc[p]]}}
> ```

or

```
 Reduce[eqs, y, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

> ```
> x == (R + p Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2])/Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2] && k == ArcTan[Csc[p]] && 
> y == (R Csc[p] + Cos[p] Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2])/Sqrt[1 + Csc[p]^2]
> ```

There is another approach to get `x` in terms of `y` and `p` :

```
Eliminate[eqs, {x, k}, InverseFunctions -> True] //
Simplify[#, x == p + R Cos[k]] &

Reduce[%, x]
```

> ```
> R^2 + 2 y Cos[p] == (p - x)^2 + y^2 + Cos[p]^2
>
> x == p - Sqrt[R^2 - y^2 + 2 y Cos[p] - Cos[p]^2] || 
> x == p + Sqrt[R^2 - y^2 + 2 y Cos[p] - Cos[p]^2]
> ```

Above, in  all cases we have to use `ReplaceAll` (i.e. `/.`) and `InverseFunction`  wherever appear `p` or `k`  to get $\;p = p(x)\;$ or $\;k = k(x)\;$.

Answer (score 6):

The Mathematica documentation has a tutorial on eliminating variables that is helpful:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html

```
Solve[{x == p + R*Cos[k], y == Cos[p] + R*Sin[k], 
  k == ArcTan[1/Sin[p]]}, y, {p}]

y -> Cot[k]^2 (R Sin[k] Tan[k]^2 - Sqrt[-Tan[k]^2 + Tan[k]^4])
```

Solving for y in terms of just x turns out to be more difficult because it is difficult to expression k in terms of x:

```
Solve[{x == p + R*Cos[k], y == Cos[p] + R*Sin[k], 
  k == ArcTan[1/Sin[p]]}, x, {y, p}]

{x -> ArcCsc[Tan[k]] + R Cos[k]}
```

The equation above is difficult to invert. There isn't a way to solve for k in terms of x except to invent a function.

```
Solve[{x == ArcCsc[Tan[k]] + R Cos[k]}, k]
{{}}
```

Also, there's a ton of inverse trig functions everywhere. Issues with branch cuts are likely.