# How can I solve Tan[t] - t == F[x] for t as a function of x?

Tags: numerics, inverse, equation-solving

How can I solve the equation `Tan[t] - t = Ax`, where `A` is a constant for `t[x]`?

I know that it's impossible to get a close-form solution, but how can I get a numerical approximation with *Mathematica*?

Comment: Have a look at `FindRoot`.

Comment: Look at this post dealing with a related problem (inverting a function) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8536/how-to-convert-a-system-of-parametric-equations-to-a-normal-equation/8543#8543

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A supplement to above two wonderful answers:

Notice that any two of the branches of curve $C$ defined by $f(t)=\tan(t)-t$ are identical with only a translation of $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}_n=(n \pi,-n \pi)^{\mathrm T}$ :

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 t \\
 \tan(t)-t \\
\end{array}
\right)+
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)n\pi
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 t+n\pi \\
 \tan(t+n\pi)-(t+n\pi) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
graph1 = Plot[Tan[t] - t, {t, -3 Pi, 3 Pi},
    PlotRange -> {-4, 12}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    MaxRecursion -> Infinity,
    PlotStyle -> Lighter[Blue],
    Exclusions -> {1/(Tan[t] - t) == 0},
    ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]
    ] // Quiet;

graph2 = Plot[Tan[t] - t, {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
    PlotRange -> {-4, 12},
    MaxRecursion -> Infinity,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick]
    ] // Quiet;

Manipulate[
 solset = t /. FindRoot[Tan[t] - t == F, {t, #}] &
   /@ (.9 \[Pi] Range[-2, 2] + .3);
 Show[{graph1, graph2},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]],
  FrameTicks -> {
    {Range[-4, 12], Range[-4, 12]},
    {Range[-5, 5, 2] Pi/2, Range[-5, 5, 2] Pi/2}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black, Bold, 20],
  Axes -> None,
  GridLines -> {None, F + Pi Range[-2, 2]},
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Lighter[Brown], Dashed],
  Epilog -> {
    Brown, Thickness[.005],
    Line[{{-3 Pi, F}, {3 Pi, F}}],
    Darker[Green, .3],
    MapIndexed[
     Disk[{#1, F} - (#2[[1]] - 3) Pi {1, -1}, .2] &,
     solset],
    Red,
    Disk[{#, F}, .2] & /@ solset,
    Lighter[Purple], Thick, Arrowheads[.03],
    MapIndexed[
     Arrow[{{#1, F} - (#2[[1]] - 3) Pi {1, -1}, {#1, F}}] &,
     solset]
    },
  ImageSize -> 600],
 {{F, 4}, -2, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So for any $F$, to get all solutions of $\tan(t)-t=F$ (the red points in above graphics), just find all intersection points of the *center branch* of $C$ and horizon lines $l_n(t)=F+n \pi$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (the green points in above graphics), then translate them with proper vectors.

To find those green points, you can adopt [Jens' `InverseFunction` method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15571/17), or [Alexei's approximate analytical solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15599/17), or it is also possible to derive an approximate formal series by functions such as `InverseSeries`:

```
seriesZero = InverseSeries[Series[Tan[t] - t, {t, 0, 9}], F]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
seriesInfinity = InverseSeries[Series[Tan[t] - t, {t, Pi/2, 9}], F]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{
   Normal@seriesZero,
   Normal@seriesInfinity,
   InverseFunction[Function[t, Tan[t] - t]][F]
   }], {F, 0, 8},
 PlotRange -> {0, Pi/2},
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ {0, .5, 1}),
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Italic, 20, Bold] & /@ {"F", "t"})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So we have a function of $x$ as
$$x\mapsto(F=F(x))\mapsto t\text{ .}$$

Answer (score 10):

The most convenient way to answer this question is by using `InverseFunction` which allows you to hide the details of finding the numerical inverse:

```
g = InverseFunction[Function[{t}, Tan[t] - t]]
```

Then your equation `Tan[t] - t == a x` can be solved by simply saying

```
g[a x]
```

Answer (score 3):

You might look for the approximate analytical solution as follows. Let us first denote y=Ax. We will substitute it back later. This is the table of solutions of your equation with 0<=y<=Pi/2:

```
tb = Table[{y, FindRoot[Tan[t] - t == y, {t, 1.2}][[1, 2]]}, {y, 
0, \[Pi]/2 - 0.02, 0.1}];
```

Now one can fit this list, and get an analytical solution out of it:

```
    Manipulate[
 lstPL = ListPlot[tb, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["y", 14, Italic], 
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(sol\)]\)", 14, Italic]}];

 ft = Fit[tb, {y^a, y^(a + b)}, y];

 pl = Plot[ft, {y, 0, \[Pi]/2}];

 Show[{lstPL, pl}, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Row[{Style["t=", 14, Italic], 
      Style[NumberForm[ft, {3, 2}], 14, Italic]}], 
    Scaled[{0.7, 0.3}]]],

 {{a, 0.306}, 0, 1}, {{b, 0.458}, 0, 1}]
```

This results in such a fit, see the image:
[image: where tsol is the solution of your equation. By varying the sliders one may get better fit with the parameters a and b (b>a)]. You get finally 
$t_{\text{sol}}\approx 1.39 (A x)^{0.31}-0.26 (A x)^{0.76}$