# How to use `FindRoot` to solve an equation containing a parameter?

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I'm trying to derive some of the results of the following paper:

*Electrodynamics of semiconductor-coated noble metal nanoshells*, JT Manassah - Physical Review A

In the paper there is matrix $\mathbf M_l^M$, defined as follows, with $\alpha$ as a parameter:

[image]

as you know, $j$ and $n$ and $h$ are different types of spherical Bessel functions.

Now, I want t solve the following equation:
$$\det ({\bf M}_l^M)=0$$

and obtain the roots in terms of $\alpha$.(
I think the equation doesn't have analytical solution, and so I tried to use `FindRoot` command, but this equation has $\alpha$ as a parameter and the roots should be founded with respect to $\alpha$. If there is no (better) way other than `FindRoot`, how can I do this using this command? I mean, how can I make `FindRoot` to solve the equation for different $\alpha$s and what is $x_0$ in the `FindRoot`? (The roots are complex numbers.)

(All I want is to obtain a plot, showing the real part of the root versus $\alpha$)

**Here is my code (definition of $\bf M$):**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV8Rs.png

Comment: Define a function in terms of alpha, as [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48521/12).

Comment: you will probably do well to use the solution at each `alpha` as the starting point for the next point. Your expression appears to have a `beta` parameter as well.. by the way.

Comment: Personally, I would be more inclined to try to help if there were *Mathematica* code for the matrix I could copy and work with.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, I know; but the letters used in the code have subscripts, superscripts, radicals, etc., so I can't copy-paste the code. I posted a picture of it for now. If there is a better way for posting the code let me know.

Comment: @george2079 $\beta$ is a number, $u$ is a function of the main variable $w$. I posted a picture of the code.

Comment: For one thing, Mma has all Bessel functions, so that you can write them down in the proper notation to enable one to help you without investing too much time. For another, I have several times shown in this forum, how to address the problem like yours. You may have a look here, for example: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15568/how-can-i-solve-tant-t-fx-for-t-as-a-function-of-x/15599#15599

Comment: so if you specify alpha does findroot work.?

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to type in the OP's code and have to worry about typos, etc.  But here's an example that in theory should show how to work with the OP's example.  One can use `NDSolve` in one of two ways to get one variable `u` in terms of another `α`.

One issue that remains is the the function are oscillatory and the equation probably has many roots for a given `α`.

Here's my matrix, more or less randomly made of Bessel functions, etc:

```
mat = {
   {SphericalBesselJ[1, α u], -SphericalHankelH1[3, α u],  0},
   {SphericalBesselY[1, α u],  SphericalBesselJ[1, α u],  -SphericalHankelH2[3, α u]},
   {0,                         SphericalBesselY[1, α u],   SphericalBesselJ[3, α u]}
  };
```

#### First Method

We can turn the equation into a differential equation by differentiating it and specifying an initial value (found with `FindRoot`).  The precision `wp` may be set to `MachinePrecision` instead of 20.  It will be faster, but the second method does not work with machine precision.  The setting `wp = 20` is used for the sake of comparison.

```
wp = 20;
maxalpha = 20;
sol = u /. First@NDSolve[{
      0 == D[Det[mat] /. {u -> u[α]}, α],         (* DE -- see Note below *)
      u[1] == (u /.                               (* IV *)
         FindRoot[Det[mat] /. α -> 1, {u, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> wp])},
     {u}, {α, 1, maxalpha}, WorkingPrecision -> wp];
```

Using `FindRoot` with high precision for the sake of comparison:

```
roots = Table[
   Through[{Re, Im}[u /. FindRoot[Det[mat], {u, sol[α]}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]]],
   {α, maxalpha}];

Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  Through[{Re, Im}[sol[α]]], {α, 1, maxalpha},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> All],
 Graphics[
  {Point@roots}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The precision of `NDSolve` (compared with `FindRoot`):

```
ListLogPlot[
 Abs /@ ((Table[sol[α], {α, maxalpha}] - roots.{1, I}) / roots.{1, I})
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Second method

The second way is to set up a DAE to trace the solution.  This is slower and less accurate on this example.  I suspect the reason is that `NDSolve` is more interested in the accuracy of the solution `α` to the DE than the accuracy of the solution `u` determined by the constraint.  So there's not much to recommend it here.  However, it can be a nice way to construct an interpolating function of a quantity that is a function of parametrized point on an integral curve.

```
wp = 20;
maxalpha = 20;
solDAE = u /. First@NDSolve[{
     0 == Det[mat] /. {u -> u[t], α -> α[t]},
     u[1] == (u /. 
        FindRoot[Det[mat] /. α -> 1, {u, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> wp]),
     α'[t] == 1, α[1] == 1},
    {u, α}, {t, 1, maxalpha},
    Method -> "StateSpace", WorkingPrecision -> wp]
```

Comparison of precision, which is about two orders of magnitude worse than the first method:

```
ListLogPlot[
 Abs /@ ((Table[solDAE[α], {α, maxalpha}] - roots.{1, I}) / roots.{1, I})
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Note:* [Stelios](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14295/stelios) pointed out that the original DE `0 == Dt@Det[mat] /. {u -> u[α]}`, which works in V9/10, does not work in V8.  So I updated it, so that the answer might work in other, hopefully all, versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Very elegant approach. Shouldn't the `(*DE*)` equation of the first method  be `0 == D[Det[mat] /. {u -> u[\[Alpha]]}, \[Alpha]]` though?

Comment: @Stelios I can't find any proof/documentation, but I believe `NDSolve` treats `Dt[α]` as `1`, since `α` is the independent variable.  So they're equivalent.  An alternative explanation is that the `Dt[α]` cancels out when `NDSolve` solves for the derivative.  In any case, your suggestion is perhaps the more normal way.  (In PDEs, on the other hand, there's a big difference between `Dt` and partial derivatives.  `Dt` might never be appropriate or work.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. The reason I posted the comment was that my MMA (version 8.0) gives an error message with the `Dt` version of the equation, whereas it runs fine with the `D[#,a]` version, and wanted to make sure that the latter is indeed equivalent with your approach.

Comment: @Stelios Yes, I get the same thing both ways on V10.1  Given that it doesn't work in earlier version, I might ought to change this answer. (But I've upvoted your comments to help draw attention to the issue.)

Comment: @Stelios And thanks for letting me know! :)